# Entity-Relation data model in Prolog

Tags: prolog, entity-relationship

I have a question about how to model an entity-relation data model in Prolog.

If I have two entities like these (expressed in plantuml form https://plantuml.com/ie-diagram):

```
entity A {
  * a_id : number
  --
  a_data : text
}

entity B {
  * b_id : number
  --
  * a_id : number
  b_data : text

B }o--|| A
```

For example:

```
a(123, 'data1').       % a(a_id, a_data).
b(456, 123, 'data2').  % b(b_id, a_id, b_data)
```

This way forces to me to generate identifiers for every new fact.

Other way:

```
a(123, 'data1').
b(456, a(123, 'data1'), 'data2').
```

In this way, if I change `a(123, _)` `a_data` value, `b` relation integrity is lost.

Another way:

```
a(123, 'data1').
b(456, a(123, _), 'data2').
```

What is the correct way of representation of this facts?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would certainly use

```
a(123, 'data1').       % a(a_id, a_data).
b(456, 123, 'data2').  % b(b_id, a_id, b_data)
```

There is no shame in having to name things ("generate new identifiers"), and you can do so easily, possibly by just by generating a new [UUID](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=uuid) randomly. I hear the modern way of modelling some structure in a relational database is to always add identifiers, even if you don't need them so as to avoid later practical problems when one wants to perform extensions and migrations. So we are in good company with the naming approach.

```
a(123, 'data1').
b(456, a(123, 'data1'), 'data2').
```

is not recommended because it copies the data for no gain, neither speed nor clarity. If you drop the fact `a(123, 'data1').` you have a tree structure rooted in `b/3` which may be adequate if the `a/2` subtree is small or varies a lot (for example one would not have specific facts to store 2x2 matrixes in relation `a`, then reference them by name from a relation `b`; one would put any matrix directly into the relation `b`).

```
a(123, 'data1').
b(456, a(123, _), 'data2').
```

makes little sense as you just have a mysterious unbound variable in the `a/2` tree inside the `b/3` tree, which just occupies memory and you can't even use it.

P.S.

One of the peculiarities of the relational model is the assumption that entities can "change over time", while still retaining some kind of "identity" (i.e. there is that suspect `UPDATE` operation). The relational database extant at time *t* is top layer of the database log. This idea seems rooted in the lack of sufficiently large disks back in the 70s. You may want to consider a model where you don't do destructive updates but add new time-stamped facts that deprecate old ones (best, transactionally). [Datomic](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Datomic-Information-Model/) (JVM/Clojure only) is a realization of that idea. Prolog doesn't seem to have much out-of-the-box support for this idea.

Comment: Thank you for UUID library. I didn't know about it.

Comment: It is a _very bad idea_ to use UUIDs as a replacement for a primary key. In the majority of cases this is equivalent to admitting that you didn't do your modelling and don't know what your primary keys are. _Please_ don't do that unless you really understand the fundamentals of relational database design, and you still have a good reason. (Yes, I have seen in it the wild too, it is one of those "bright ideas" that are "so crazy it might just work".) Downvoting because of this, sorry.

Comment: @TA_intern Use a synthetic numeric id then, you know the ones labeled AUTOINCREMENT. Call it an SKU. Same energy. The search for "primary keys that are not synthetic" may sometimes succeed, but generally it's not worth it and there more interesting things to do. These are not crazy ideas, they are ideas born from practice, although sometimes things go overboard.

Comment: Yes but you know how it goes. There is a well understood way of doing something; but it requires study (since it is well understood and there is a lot of knowledge that you can't avoid). Then, in some very particular situation, people who already have all the knowledge realize there is another way to approach their specific problem. Then, people _who do not have the knowledge_ and _do not understand the implications_ jump to conclusions. This is pervasive, esp. in software development, where no one knows nearly as much as they think they do.